# Receive FaceTime calls dialed to my iPhone number

Tags: macos, ios, facetime

Since iOs 6 and Mountain Lion I'm able to receive iMessages sent to my cellular number both on my iPhone and my Mac Book.

Is it possible to do the same with FaceTime? I would like to receive FaceTime calls dialed to my iPhone number also on my Mac Book.

I tried to configure it in FaceTime preferences but it only allows my to add email addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use your iPhone number for FaceTime on your Mac, but I have heard of cases where the phone number didn't get recognized at first.

Make sure that you have 10.8.2 installed. Then try toggling FaceTime off and on in your iPhone's settings. That re-registers it with Apple's servers, and should list the phone number as an option. If it still doesn't appear as an option on your Mac, turn off FaceTime on the Mac (not quitting, actually disabling it from the menu), then sign back in to it.

Comment: Thanks. I turned off and then on FaceTime on my Mac and it showed my phone number.